# SQL Calculation of PRIMARY KEY (autoincrement)

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, auto-increment

assuming I have an empty table "`TABLE_1`". Then I use;

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLE_1 ON
```

to insert some data (including primary key).

Afterwards I deactivate `IDENTITY_INSERT` and want to insert other values (the default way, i.e. without the primary key). How does `SQL` calculate the new primary key value? Is it something like:

```
MAX(ID) + 1
```

Thanks in advance
Eugen

Comment: It's a **lot more complicated** than this! And don't use this `MAX()+1` approach yourself - it's **not concurrency safe** and you'll end up with duplicates!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an internal implementation detail that you should worry about. Usually when someone asks a question like this, they are asking about some detail to a perceived solution to a problem. You might be better off telling us the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some testing:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp.test (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    val NVARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO tmp.test (val) values ('run_1.1')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT tmp.test ON
INSERT INTO tmp.test (ID, val) values
(112, 'run_2.1'), (2, 'run_2.2'), (45, 'run_2.3')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tmp.test OFF

INSERT INTO tmp.test (val) values ('run_3.1'), ('run_3.2')

select * from tmp.test
```

The result is:

```
ID  val
1   run_1.1
2   run_2.2
45  run_2.3
112 run_2.1
113 run_3.1
114 run_3.2
```

That means, no reseed is required :-), which is great.

P.S.: I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Good to know. Just learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from SQL Server documentation:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx

**If the value inserted is larger than the current identity value for the table, SQL Server automatically uses the new inserted value as the current identity value.**